# About installing Mathematica on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, mathematica

I followed the first set of instructions here to install it from a ".sh" file,
http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453

At Step 4 and 5 I chose the folder "~/Desktop/Mathematica" as the folder to create the "installation directory" and the place where the "scripts will be created".

I had made that folder before I started the installation process but the installation process couldn't see it. It apparently made a new directory by this name at that location. But I can't see this directory in my Desktop!

How do I now actually activate and run Mathematica?

Comment: Is it possible that in your Ubuntu version (language) "Desktop" is named differently? ("Bureaublad" in Dutch for example)

Comment: No! Can I somehow remove this installation and try again?

Comment: It is difficult to look into it, since it is not free software, impossible to downoad.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your home directory and see if you have a directory named "~".  Your use of quotes may have caused the problem, replacing the shell home directory shortcut with the actual tilde character.  See if the files are present.  Rename the '~' directory (and use quotes since you mean the "~" directory,not your home directory) to something less confusing like Mathematica, and move it to the Desktop directory.

Comment: I don't have any folder in my "Home" called "~". And I didn't use the quotes in what I actually typed at the terminal. I used the quotes here to highlight.